# Polynomials invariant under specific permutations or subgroups of $S_n$.

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions, young-tableaux

The Schur polynomials or the power symmetric polynomials are such that they are invariant under the whole $S_n$. Are there polynomials which are invariant only under a chosen permutation group element or invariant only under a chosen subgroup or conjugacy class of $S_n$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. For example, any $\sigma = (12)(34)$ invariant polynomial will be a $(12)$ invariant polynomial. What are you looking for exactly ?

Comment: But what is a polynomial that is invariant under $(12)(34)$? What can we do with specific permutations or conjugacy classes or subgroups?

Comment: $x_1^1x_2^2x_3^3x_4^4 + x_1^2x_2^1x_3^4x_4^3$ is invariant under $(12)(34)$ and the idenity only

Comment: Thanks mercio for your example ! I should think more carefully before commenting ...

Comment: @mercio Thanks for the example! This is what I am looking for! Can you say something about how this is generalized? What do we know about these?

Comment: well if you have a subgroup $H$ you can simply pick $\sum_{g \in H} \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{g(i)}$, and it should be fixed by exactly $H$

Comment: For specific elements what do we do? Are these polynomials known by some name? Is there any structural understanding of them?